# Youtube-style controls for video & audio in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, audio, video, hotkeys, video-playback

When playing a 'plain' audio or video file in Chrome, such as when directly accessing a .mp3 or .mp4 file on your local storage, the default Chrome player is very bare-bones - a play/pause button, volume/mute control, full-screen button, picture-in-picture button, and a progress/scrub bar.

I find this inconvenient, and long for the intuitive hotkeys present when viewing videos on Youtube or many streaming websites - features such as skipping 5 seconds with the left & right arrows, or adjusting playback speed with shift+< & shift+>. Basic other features, such as looping, also seem to be absent.

Is there any way to enable similar control features when viewing a 'plain' audio or video file (whether locally or otherwise)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install [Video Speed Controller](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-speed-controller/nffaoalbilbmmfgbnbgppjihopabppdk). It is an extension that allows to:

> Speed up, slow down, advance and rewind HTML5 audio/video with shortcuts

After installing, go to the extensions page and enable "Allow access to file URLs"

[image]

It adds controls at the top left of the browser's video player.

[image]

In its settings page, you can enable whether the controller should be hidden, change its opacity, its shortcuts, etc.

[image]